# Fragment doesn't call onSaveInstanceState when swiping ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-viewpager, android-lifecycle

I'm having an issue with the ViewPager where my ListView is loosing it's scroll position.

The state of the ListView can easily be stored and restored using:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_cool_things, container, false);

    AdvListView listView = (AdvListView) v.findViewById(R.id.lv0);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener( mOnListItemClicked );

    if (null != savedInstanceState)
    {
        listView.onRestoreListViewInstanceState(savedInstanceState.getParcelable("list_state"));
    }

    mListView = listView;

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState) 
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putParcelable("list_state", mListView.onSaveListViewInstanceState());
}
```

However the problem is that when fragments are being swiped `onDestroyView()` gets called but never calls `onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState)`.

Rotating the screen and such restores the `ListView` state just fine but swiping I can't figure out how to restore the list properly.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Update 12/17/11:**
I actually found the correct way to save the content of the Fragments.  You must use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.  This adapter properly saves the state of the fragment! :)

**OLD:**
Well I found a way to do this.. Please share your input if you believe this is a huge no no! :P

Here is my FragmentBase class that fixed this issue:

```
public abstract class FragmentBase extends Fragment
{
    private boolean mInstanceAlreadySaved;
    private Bundle mSavedOutState;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        if (null == savedInstanceState && null != mSavedOutState) {
            savedInstanceState = mSavedOutState;
        }

        mInstanceAlreadySaved = false;
        return onCreateViewSafe(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState) 
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mInstanceAlreadySaved = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() 
    {
        if (!mInstanceAlreadySaved)
        {
            mSavedOutState = new Bundle();
            onSaveInstanceState( mSavedOutState );
        }

        super.onStop();
    }

    public abstract View onCreateViewSafe (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState);
}
```

Comment: My own temporary solution is to just write my stuff to the SharedPreferences in OnPause(), and get them back in OnCreateView(...). This however, forces you to access the attaching activity to get the Sharedpreferences (getActivity().getSharedPreferences(...)), and you might also need to explicitly delete unwanted stuff when the activity is torn down (depending on what you're storing, ofc). Hope someone has a better way! :)

Comment: "FragmentPagerAdapter will detach each fragment as you swipe through the list, but keep them in memory so they can simply be reattached when the user swipes back. If you have a larger number of Fragments, the FragmentStatePagerAdapter is worth considering as it will remove them, with the downside being they need to be rebuilt as the user swipes back to them. So, if you have fewer, more complex fragments the FragmentPagerAdapter makes sense, but consider FragmentStatePagerAdapter for larger sets." (Android Dev Blog)

Comment: The proposed solution is therefore not optimal for a small number of Fragments.